# RavenDB attachments with authentication

Tags: ravendb

I am running RavenDB server build 2174 with the following lines added to the Raven.Server.exe.config file:

```
<add key="Raven/Authorization/Windows/RequiredGroups" value="localhost\Administrators"/>
<add key="Raven/AnonymousAccess" value="None"/>
```

I have also setup an ApiKey that my application uses to interact with the RavenDB server and database.  The ApiKey has been given Admin rights (checked the admin checkbox) for the database that I am working with.

With the configuration given above, I am trying to load attachments from the RavenDB database using the DatabaseCommands.GetAttachment() method.  Whenever I do this, I get a 401 (Unauthorized) response.  I have been able to get it working by using the With() method on the DatabaseCommands object to pass in authentication using a login and password combination from the Administrators group.  Here is the line of code that does this

```
SiteDocumentStore.DatabaseCommands
                 .With(new NetworkCredential("login", "password", "domain"))
                 .GetAttachment(attachment_key);
```

So my question is, how can I use the GetAttachment() method without having to use the With() and pass in login credentials?  The DocumentStore already has the ApiKey and it using it for all the other commands without the need to do anything special.  In fact the PutAttachment() method works without having to use the With() method, so why can't the GetAttachment()?  Is this an oversight or a bug?  Or is there something that I'm just no getting?

Answer (score 0):

You are NOT using the Api Key when you are using login/pass, and it should automatically authenticate with the right Api Key for you. 
We just identified a bug in using Api Keys in certain circustances, please wait for the next build (2176), which should resolve it.

Comment: Perfect, thank you Ayende. Just as an fyi, I knew that it would not use the ApiKey when you use the login/pass.  I am just currently using that as a workaround because the ApiKey was not working.  It was just to let people know that it worked fine with using login/pass, but was not working when just using ApiKey.  Thanks again for the great product and the quick response!

Comment: Seems to be working great in build 2176 and later. Thanks again for getting this fixed.